# Transforming XML using XSL style sheet

Tags: xml, xslt

I am developing an application were I need to transform XML documents that look like this:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='ISO-8859-1'?>
<!DOCTYPE words SYSTEM "words.dtd">
<words>
<word id="word_1">Alfa</word>
<word id="word_2">Beta</word>
<word id="word_3">Gamma</word>
<word id="word_4">Pi</word>
</words>
```

Using a XSLT stylesheet. I would like the result of the transformation to be (in this case) `Alfa Beta Gamma Pi` and this is the XSL I am using:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='ISO-8859-1'?>

<xsl:transform version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

<xsl:template match="/">
  <html>
  <body>
    <xsl:for-each select="words/word">
    <tr>
      <td><xsl:value-of select="@id"/></td>
      <td>
      <xsl:attribute name="word">
        <xsl:value-of select="@id" />
      </xsl:attribute>
      </td>
    </tr>
    </xsl:for-each>
  </body>
  </html>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

The result is not the one I am looking for. What do I have to change in the XSLT?

Comment: You're pulling the id attribute twice in both value-of arguments. If you want to output the text, you want to change one of the values-of to select=word or select=. as seen below.

Comment: If you're generating HTML, then you don't want to generate an attribute named "word", as there is no such attribute in HTML and it will simply be ignored.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let me guess... it's outputing the ID instead of the value.

You probably want:

```
<td><xsl:value-of select="."/></td>
```

or

```
<td><xsl:value-of select="text()"/></td>
```

Answer (score 1):

The stylesheet is missing the opening `<xsl:stylesheet` element.

Comment: Probably a copy/paste issue, because I see the ending one - but good catch!

Comment: Yeh, I've +1'd your answer as it looks like that sorted @haritz out.

Comment: `xsl:transform` is valid also. See http://www.w3schools.com/xsl/xsl_transformation.asp assuming the start and end tag match :)